# Can we make the "ask your own question" a button instead of a link?

Tags: feature-request, questions, asking-questions, not-an-answer

At the moment when you scroll down past all the answers on a page you see the box to write your own answer and a nice big blue button "Post Your Answer". There is also a guidance to ask your own question, but the big blue button wins quite often. This results in a lot of NAAs asking for clarifications or follow-up questions.

Can we make the second button the same as the big blue button?
For example:

[image]

All I did was apply the same CSS classes to the link.

Comment: I ajm so with you. Probably would put the two buttons right side by side however

Comment: Are you saying that you want this new "Ask your own question" button to navigate the user to the Ask Question wizard with the current contents of the answer textarea used for the beginnings of a question?

Comment: @Makyen No. Just navigate them. If they started typing here already they can copy it themselves. All I want is to have both buttons have the same prominence on the screen.

Comment: @Dharman Then, I disagree that the same formatting should be used. The blue button formatting is primarily used on Stack Overflow to indicate the button to click on in order to submit something. I'm not against making the link to "ask you own question" more prominent, but using the same formatting as the "Post your answer" button is more confusing.

Comment: @Makyen I am open to suggestions. I just think it would be small cost to help with the notorious NAA problem. Anything to make the Ask a question button more visible would help.

Comment: I doubt that introducing a button would change anything with regards to NAA's. There's no mistaken the headline "Your Answer". If the link is changed to a button, it may just introduce a new problem with people posting "Thank you"'s and other NAA's as Questions and/or people posting actual Answers (as Questions), but no one other than the poster would know which original Question their new Question answers.

Comment: @Scratte That is less of a problem. Questions are better curated. If you see nonsense question you downvote and close and the person asking 3 such questions gets a ban. There are also more checks for asking question, which should indicate to the confused user that they are asking a new question not posting an answer. If we are afraid people will easily misclick we can make it other color e.g. green or red, but the same size.

Comment: @Scratte Also there's plenty of languages where there is no adequate translation for the word answer. People who's English is not a native language like me can easily misunderstand what "answer" means. For example when translated to my language it means "Reply" and the meaning is lost, because "Thank you" is a valid reply.

Comment: I was under the impression that most NAA's were make by new user, and that those went directly to First Posts or Late Answers, where they're handled. My impression of the problem is that those users do not read the tour. I'm not entirely sure there is a UI fix for people who do not want to introduce themselves to the basics. Even if there is a new button, the old one will still translate to "Reply".